# Wordpress / Woocommerce My Account Subpages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a working custom page (menu) tab using all the appropriate functions, actions/filters which I have setup and it works as intended and now I am looking to add additional child/subpages to the process setup as `https://www.website.com/myaccount/books/` to include `https://www.website.com/myaccount/books/create/` and `/modify/abc123/`.

Obviously this is a front-end function, and I'm requesting the assistance of the SE community as to the best way to proceed.

**my-account-books.php**

```
global $current_user;

$query_var = get_query_var( 'books' );

if ( !empty ( $query_var ) ) {

    if ( $query_var == 'create' ) {

        var_dump( $query_var ); // Returns: string(6) "create"
        // Output Code
    }

    if ( $query_var == 'modify' ) {

        var_dump( $query_var ); // Returns: string(6) "modify"
        // Output Code

    }

    if ( $query_var == 'modify/' . <<this value>> ) {

        // Output Code
}

elseif ( empty ( $query_vars ) ) {

    /* The below code works, I just added it to show the process.
       I want to use the identical code in standalone /modify/.
       I was thinking about using get_template_path('partials/books'); 
    */

    $args = array ( 
    'post_type' => '1234_books',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'pending' ),
    'author' => $current_user->ID, 
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

            /* Code has been removed to simplify post and 
               not relevant to this enquiry */

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                the_post_thumbnail ( array( 150, 150 ) );

            }
            else {

                // Placeholder (300 x 300)

            }

        endwhile;

    endif;

}
```

The bit that I'm having problems with is separating the query_var within the url for example, if the address is `.../modify/abc123/` the query_var result is `string(13) modify/abc123"` and I need to extract the `abc123`. Would using `explode( '/' $query_var )` be the best option in this scenario? And then do a `$mod_query = new WP_Query...` to extract the 'abc123' from the query_var and then display the loop based on the returned information, or is there another way that I can achieve this? In addition, is the provided code the most efficient way to undertake this task overall?

Thank-you.

**== UPDATE ==**

I ended up using this for the code and it works but is this the best way to undertake this particular task?

```
$query_var = get_query_var( 'books' );

$book_id = explode( '/', $query_var );

if ( empty ( $book_id[0] ) || ( !isset ( $book_id[0] ) ) ) :

    echo 'Book Dashboard';
    // Code Goes Here

elseif ( !empty ( $book_id[0] ) && ( $book_id[0] == 'add' ) ) :

    echo 'Add Book';
    // Code Goes Here.

elseif ( !empty ( $book_id[0] ) && ( $book_id[0] == 'modify' ) ) :

    if ( !isset ( $book_id[1] ) ) :

        echo 'Modify Book. No ID Provided';
        // Code Goes Here.

    elseif ( isset ( $pet_id[1] ) ) :

        echo 'Modify Book. Book ID: ' . $book_id[1];
        // Code Goes Here.

    endif;

elseif ( !empty ( $book_id[0] ) && ( $book_id[0] == 'remove' ) ) :

    echo 'Remove Book';
    // Code Goes Here.

endif;
```

Comment: So what happens when you try your idea?

Comment: @Howard-e Updated my question to reply to you.